# Overwrite git repository without losing commits

Tags: git, merge

My problem:

I want to build a angular library and host it on a private git repository. To deploy my library, I need to push the contents of the dist/my_project folder, which gets removed every time I build my library. This means I cannot keep a local git history, since the local git folder gets removed.

Initially I just git pushed -f after a git init, but this clears the history on the remote, meaning I can't use versioning on this repository.

I have found a solution that works, but the "git merge" strategy seems to be considered a very dodgy thing to do. Is there a better way to do this?

What I currently do to make sure I'm able to keep previous versions.

```
ng build mylib
cd ./dist/mylib/
git init
git remote add origin MY_REMOTE
git fetch
git add .
git commit -am 'version bump'
git merge origin/master -s ours --allow-unrelated-histories
git commit -am 'version bump'
git tag $1
git push --set-upstream origin master
git push --tags
cd ../../
```

It is important

Comment: I was first planning to post my current solution as an answer on this question, but I hesitated since it seems a bit dodgy.

Comment: So the problem is you delete your .git directory -- Try to play around with --work-tree option maybe that is what you are looking for.

Comment: I looked into options with `git worktree`, but it seems a bit of hassle to keep a separate working main git directory as I think this would complicate the setup.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found it the best way to temporarily move the `.git` folder as it seemed the most straightforward, least dodgy approach:

so basically:

```
mv ./dist/mylib/.git ./dist/mylib-backup-git
ng build mylib
mv ./dist/mylib-backup-git ./dist/mylib/.git
```

Keeping the `.git` repository also allowed me to use branches, which further improved versioning.